# how to disable enum if bool is not true in inspector unity

Tags: unity

I want to enable an `enum` when a `bool` value is true through the inspector and disable it when the value is `false`.
Please see the relevant code below:

```
public bool hasWeapon;

[System.Serializable] 
public enum WeaponType {HandGun, Sword, ShotGun, Spear, BowAndArrow};

public WeaponType weaponType;
```

From the above code `weaponType` should only appear in the inspector if `hasWeapon` is `true`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own inspector script where you manually draw the layout of the inspector for the type you're interested in. With custom inspector scripts you can display the information you want and need depending on any value of your object.

Plenty of tutorials on it :https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector